# Jquery autocomplete in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, autocomplete

I am new in jsp and so in javascript and i am trying to create an autocomplete form with two text fields. Also i want the second one to take some value automatic according to the value of the first one. Well, i did a little research and i found in another topic a code snippet. The think is that when i put it in a single jsp page in netbeans it doesn't works.I think something is missing. Can you please help with that. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<input id='fruit' name='fruit' type='text'>
<input id='details' name='details' type='text'>

<script>

var x = [
{ label : 'apple', value : 'Delicious' },
{ label : 'kiwi', value : 'Yummy' },
{ label : 'kiwiooo', value : 'aaa' },
{ label :  'lemon', value : 'Sour' }
];

$( "#fruit" ).autocomplete({
source: x,
focus : function(){ return false; }
})
.on( 'autocompleteresponse autocompleteselect', function( e, ui ){
var t = $(this),
details = $('#details'),
label = ( e.type === 'autocompleteresponse' ? ui.content[0].label :  ui.item.label ),
value = ( e.type === 'autocompleteresponse' ? ui.content[0].value : ui.item.value );
t.val( label );
details.val( value );
return false;
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u3m8sqwm/3/)
UPDATED

Comment: Post your code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: I think it may need some libraries.

Comment: yes, you can find it left side of your fiddle window. External resources you can give the link.

Comment: OK. it works now on FIDDLE because  i added jquery ui 1.9.2. But how can i fix that in my jsp page on netbeans?

Comment: Got your updated fiddle. It autocomplete's first textbox and fills the related data to the second one. Now tell what you think is missing? Add libraries properly. First add css files and add your jQuery and jQuery-UI script files in order and check.

Comment: I don't know how to set a path for jQuery ui 1.9.2. in my jsp file.

Comment: Add like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)